# Remembering webpage location (url)

Tags: javascript, node.js, design-patterns, express

Just to clarify, this question is about design pattern rather than asking for help on a specific code issue. 
The question is specific to how to store urls that was used to access the page, or have previously been used, when reloading pages. The two use cases below are only listed to help clarify this question. 
Another way to ask the same question is. If someone calls your webpage, with say
www.mywebpage.com/index.html&testmypage. What is the smoothest way to pick this up, let the user log in and then be presented with the testmypage option from whatever framework you use to navigate on the front end. In this case it uses angular states. 
However, I suspect that whatever way you resolve this issue, you will need to manage it on the server then "send it" back to the front end.

======== original question =========

Working on an application, actually two applications, and have the same query about both, how to remember the url and what is the best or smoothest way to do so.

So use case 1 is, I have a webpage that uses three other webpages (and three internal ones, to display six different parts. So one is a wiki, one is a time reporting system, some news pages, and all is on six pages or tabs. In this case I want the webpage to "remember" where the user is on all six tabs. So if you go around looking at news, then flip to the time reporting, and then want to go back to news, it remembers what news page you where on rather than taking you to listing. (the different pages are all in iframes)

Second is when the user logs in, so I want to be able to send a link to a secure location, say invite them to a discussion, but they will be presented with a login prompt (using node passport). The problem is that express have a default location it will send you to once you have logged in, and if you use external authentication (say gmail or facebook) that will include a callback.

I could potentially store the information in a cookie, or I could maybe add something to the callback and make internal auth handle it by just remembering the url it was asked to supply in the first place, but can see some headaches with both solutions, so thought I would ask if there is a standard or ridiculously smart solution.

Comment: With 172 Rep you should know better how to ask questions here. Please visit the [help] to see how before this is voted down and clsed as too broad, not to mention you ask two questions

Comment: I can see where you are coming from, and I have tried to clarify my question, but I put it under the tag design-pattern because this was a wider question on useful design rather than a direct issue with the code.